# Stacking Wild Shape and Shapechange

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, wild-shape

So, I've been reviewing the abilities of Shapechange and Wild Shape. My big wonder is whether or not they stack. In other words, could I feasibly Shapechange into a creature that will be my "base" creature (I.e. something with great innate abilities), and then wild-shape on top of that (I.e. for powerful melee abilities).

---

### Problem #1

The big keypoint here is about the whether or not I can use an (Su) class ability while Shapechanged. To quote Shapechange:

> you lose your own supernatural abilities.

Shapechange, however, says it functions as polymorph, which in turn functions as Atler Self. Now, to quote Alter Self:

> Your class...remain[s] the same.

Now, the retention or loss of supernatural and extraordinary abilities in these spells revolves around a single word: **form**. This leads me to presume that the "losing my own supernatural abilities" clause relates only to those derived from form, not from classes. To expand on the Shapechage quote:

> You gain all extraordinary and supernatural abilities (both attacks and qualities) of the assumed **form**, but you lose your own supernatural abilities.

Since the "losing supernatural abilities" appears in that clause, I think it is form based. I would, however, like a second opinion.

---

### Problem #2

The second point is that, assuming I *can* use a class-based Su, can I Wild Shape? My thought is that since they follow two different ability types (Alternate Form and Alter Self) that this would feasibly work.

Here is an example of what I mean (and yes, this campaign is of suitable power level so that I'm not breaking anything ;D):

**1)** Shapechange into Chronotyryn. Get nice spells, feats, and the wonderful double-actions.

**2)** Wildshape into, say, an Ironmaw tree for tentacles longer than many creatures' movement speeds.

In theory,  I would still retain the abilities of by "base" form because I technically *am* the Chronotyryn, since Wild Shape is more of a "body suit" mentality where as Shapechange is a literal type change.

In the eyes of some there is a Shapechange and Wild-shape conflict. In this case, the key factors are the difference between becoming a polymorph effect and an assume form effect. As a polymorph, Shapechange specifies that you quite literally change type and subtype to *become* the new creature. Wild shape quite clearly specifies that you do *not* truly "become" the new creature -- your HP, type, subtype, etc. do not change at all (generally, there are exceptions to this).

Secondly, Polymorph effects are quite often permanent. Assume form abilities, however, never are -- they are merely a shifting of the form of the same creature.

---

**Answers??**

Comment: How do you reconcile both *shapechange* and wild shape referencing the creature's original (or natural) form?

Comment: @HeyICanChan I would say that, in my view, Shapechange literally changes the creature ala polymorph. For example, you could apply a *permanent* polymorph affect to a creature, and it would retain it's class abilities (assuming the form didn't prohibit them, i.e. lacking hands to use a sword)...including Wild Shape. Shapechange is just empowered fluid polymorphing.  You essentially *are* the new creature, and that becomes your base form. I will edit in a point to address this.

Comment: I'm working on an answer to this, and I want to confirm I'm understanding the essence of this ask. My answer tentatively addresses these two questions: *When a creature in its original form assumes a second different form then assumes a third different form, is that second form now its original form?* and *Does a creature that's used the spell* shapechange *to assume a different form keep supernatural abilities derived from classes and levels?* Would answers to those two questions address this ask or is there something I'm missing?

Comment: On the second point about Su, you're spot on. With the first point, the key factor is *When a creature assumes a form using a polymorph/transmutation spell effect and then assumes a third form using an Alternate Form (Su) effect (wild shape in this case), is the second form treated as it's "new" original form (for the duration of the spell)?* I think that'll cover it :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to paraphrase the questions; I hope that's okay.

### When a creature in its original form (form #0) uses a spell of the [subschool polymorph](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/ex/20060501a&page=5) to assume different form (form #1) *then* uses a [supernatural ability](http://dndsrd.net/specialAbilities.html#supernatural-abilities) to assume *another* different form (form #2), is form #1 now the creature's original form for the purposes of form #2?

This DM is of the opinion that the short answer to that question is *No*. This DM is also of the opinion that the much longer and more complicated answer is *No, but the effects of form #1 can be suppressed by form #2 until the effect causing form #2 is itself ended or suppressed at which time form #1 reasserts itself… and so on.* (Note that this DM and player *totally* understands *both* the question *and* the desire!)

Let me first say it's totally possible to get hung up on the question *What's a creature's original form?* because the game never provides an absolute technical answer to that question *and* because the game uses what this reader believes are synonyms for the term *original form* apparently randomly. A contemporary reader attempting a legalistic analysis of the various texts is confronted with a host of seemingly different terms in different contexts. However, to this reader, the same thing is meant by all these terms (see below).

> #### Examples of *natural form*, *normal form*, and *original form*
>
> The term ***natural form*** is used by the supernatural ability [wild shape](http://dndsrd.net/druid.html#druid-wild-shape) (*Player's Handbook* (2012) 37), the 4th-level Sor/Wiz spell [*polymorph*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsPtoR.html#polymorph) [trans] (*Player's Handbook* 263), and the descriptions of, for example, the [quasit](http://dndsrd.net/monstersDtoDe.html#quasit-demon) (*Monster Manual* 46), [succubus](http://dndsrd.net/monstersDtoDe.html#succubus-demon) (47), [imp](http://dndsrd.net/monstersDtoDe.html#imp-devil) (56), [doppelganger](http://dndsrd.net/monstersDitoDo.html#doppelganger) (67–8) and [lycanthrope](http://dndsrd.net/monstersKtoL.html#lycanthrope) (170).
>
> The term ***normal form*** is used by the 2nd-level Sor/Wiz spell [*alter self*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsAtoB.html#alter-self) [trans] (*PH* 197), in the description of the [chaos beast](http://dndsrd.net/monstersBtoC.html#chaos-beast)'s supernatural ability corporeal form (*Monster Manual* 33), and in the [lycanthrope](http://dndsrd.net/monstersKtoL.html#lycanthrope) entry's description on Changing Form pre-errata (*Monster Manual* (2003) 178). (Errata changes the section's effects thereby omitting the term rather than changing the term deliberately.)
>
> Both of the terms ***natural form*** and ***original form*** term are used by the supernatural ability [alternate form](http://dndsrd.net/monsterTypes.html#alternate-form) (*Monster Manual* 305), but the [D&D Glossary on *alternate form*](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/glossary&term=Glossary_dnd_alternateform&alpha=A) uses only the term *original form* in its entry.

This reader can imagine an argument saying that because there's no rhyme or reason to the use of these terms then each term *must* be a *different* term that has a different definition that *must* be gleaned from the term's use exclusively in its own context. Thus *each time* such a term's used a new definition must be created. That's reasonable, I guess, but that's *pretty freakin' intense*, and *this* reader wouldn't do that. Nonetheless, if that's useful in pursuit of a goal, this reader says *Go for it*.

This reader is *far* more comfortable with the term *original form* plus all of its many possible synonyms meaning *The creature when any effect that changes its form is absent or suppressed.* *That* is a creature's original form—its form #0. Using this definition means that typically when a creature starting in form #0 changes to form #1 then changes *again* to form #2, form #1 is ended or suppressed in favor of form #2.

That *suppressed* part in that definition above *is* really important. The *Player's Handbook* on Combining Magical Effects, in part, says

> Several other general rules apply when spells or magical effects operate in the same place:…
>
> *One Effect Makes Another Irrelevant:* Sometimes, one spell can render a later spell irrelevant. For example, if a wizard is using a *shapechange* spell to take the shape of an eagle, a *polymorph* spell could change her into a goldfish. The *shapechange* spell is not negated, however, and since the *polymorph* spell has no effect on the recipient’s special abilities, the wizard could use the *shapechange* effect to take any form the spell allows whenever she desires. If a creature using a *shapechange* effect becomes petrified by a *flesh to stone* spell, however, it turns into a mindless, inert statue, and the *shapechange* effect cannot help it escape. (171–2)

(Note that it doesn't matter if, for example, a creature uses a spell to change form then uses a supernatural ability to change form; both are magical effects so this covers both plus spell-like abilities and, by extension (and probably transparency), psionics as well.)

So in that example the wizard (form #0) used the [*shapechange*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsS.html#shapechange) effect to assume eagle form (form #1) but is then forced by the [*baleful polymorph*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsAtoB.html#baleful-polymorph) effect to assume goldfish form (fort #2). Form #1 has been made *irrelevant* by form #2 because the wizard is a goldfish not an eagle. The wizard's *shapechange* spell hasn't ended—it hasn't been dispelled, its duration continues—, but its effect—form #1—has been temporarily suppressed by the *baleful polymorph* effect that changed the wizard into form #2. The wizard on her turn can take a free action to use the ongoing *shapechange* effect to assume a form other than form #0 or form #2, and that transformation into a different form functionally *swaps* form #2 (goldfish) and form #1 (let's say [iron golem](http://dndsrd.net/monstersG.html#iron-golem) but it could've as easily been again an eagle). The *shapechange* effect (form #2) now renders irrelevant the *baleful polymorph* effect (form #1)… temporarily.

Upon the duration expiring of her *shapechange* effect (form #2), the wizard normally would automatically assume her original form (form #0) but she's prevented from doing so by the permanent duration of the *baleful polymorph* effect (form #1). She must do something to end that *baleful polymorph* effect (form #1) while she's using the *shapechange* effect to assume a different form (form #2) or else when the *shapechange* effect ends she'll end up *again* as a darn goldfish!

And, yes, *that* is *also* complicated, too, but it's *playable*. Changing form *in general* is *already* one of the most complicated things in the game, requiring math, patience, research, and a whole lot of time, *and* one of the most *unbalanced* effects in a game not well known for being balanced in the first place. My own experience with definitions other than one given above (like, for example, *original form* meaning *a creature's previous form*) is that they'll soon have a DM pulling out his hair. This DM advises instituting a definition of *original form* as meaning *The creature when any effect that changes its form is absent or suppressed* lest confusion and frustration reign.

*Addendum:* After writing this, I reread Skip Williams's [Rules of the Game](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/arch/rg) columns "Polymorphing Revisited." [Part 4](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/rg/20060523a) includes the following:

> Effects that work some sort of physical change on the recipient fall under the rules for effects that render each other irrelevant. For example, spells such as *fins to feet* and *girallon's blessing* from the *Spell Compendium* both transform the recipient physically…. Since a creature gains the assumed form's body layout and limbs upon changing, the change in form makes either spell irrelevant. For example, if a creature using either spell assumes the form of a horse through alternate form, it becomes a typical horse, with four legs and four feet with hooves. If the creature later reverts to its original form, either spell still applies to the creature, provided the spell's duration hasn't run out.

Despite this reader ([and others](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/60044/what-is-wrong-with-the-dd-3-5-faq)) sometimes disagreeing with Williams's columns, in this case his opinion and the reader's line up.

### Does a creature that's used the spell *shapechange* to assume a different form keep supernatural abilities derived from classes and levels?

A creature that uses a *shapechange* effect to assume a different from loses all its original form's supernatural abilities. Despite the creature having kept its classes, levels, and supernatural abilities by way of the spell *polymorph* then the spell *alter self*, the spell *shapechange* says, "You gain all extraordinary and supernatural abilities (both attacks and qualities) of the assumed form, but you lose your own supernatural abilities." The *shapechange* spell "functions like *polymorph*, except" for the listed exceptions among which this—the loss of supernatural abilities related to the original form—numbers one. Having *druid 17* written on one's character sheet doesn't change the *shapechange* spell. Simply put, while a a *shapechange* effect is being used to assume a different form, a creature just *can't* activate the supernatural ability wild shape.

However, all is not lost! A creature that's the subject of a *shapechange* effect yet opts *not* to use that effect to assume a different from its original (or opts to return to its original form) *can* use its supernatural abilities in that form (form #0). The spell *shapechange* doesn't itself inherently quash the creature's ability to use its supernatural abilities; it's *using* the spell *shapechange* to assume a different form that does. Thus a druid who casts the *shapechange* spell yet remains in or returns to form #0 *can* use the supernatural ability wild shape to assume form #1 then use the *shapechange* effect to assume form #2. Were the *shapechange* effect subsequently ended or suppressed while the duration of the wild shape continued, the creature would go from form #2 to form #1 instead of from form #2 to form #0.

Comment: Very thorough, thank you. Not *quite* as broken as a it could, but it makes sense, especially since the PlanShep's wild-shape is *essentially* a shapechange effect. Also, considering adjusting my shape is a free action, no big deal. In a few levels I'll have Shapechange *persisted*...and since I can wild shape as a swift action..."losing" things is more a matter of swift/free actions than it is a serious issue. Definitely a tangled mess, though!

Comment: @Alphaeus Wow. Do the DM a favor and *have everything computed beforehand!* Personally, I struggle keeping track of dudes when they  just rage; I can't imagine the logistical nightmare of tracking multiple form changes during a single turn! Good luck, and happy to help.

Comment: Oh don't worry, I've got a Gdoc for him that we both keep up so that I update every level with newly accessible forms as well as fusing my stats with the old ones. Definitely paperwork heavy, but I'm enjoying the feel of the build.